# Oracle DB - How to get average transaction size

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to get the average size of a transaction sent & executed on an Oracle database?

I can get variables such as User Transactions per sec, IOPS, Physical read/writes, but not a the average size of a user transaction.

Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? number of rows, storage volume affected, or something else? you won't see this mentioned because it is a mostly meaningless statistic. Best way to estimate that on a broad scale - in my opinion - would be to evaluate the volume of redo logs generated in MB or GB per transaction in a given period of time, but it will have no real meaning compared to the other practical measures of throughput you've already mentioned, or the actual amount of redo generated.

Comment: Fair question. What I'm looking for is how much data is written and read in kb/mb/... on average per transaction. I feel that physical read/write operations could contain overhead  ...

Comment: Every transaction will contain overhead of some kind (undo, redo, temp i/o); those physical read/write operations are *part* of the transaction, so you can't really separate that out. Best you can do is the overall redo log generation rate. This isn't a metric that has practical value for monitoring or performance tuning, so it isn't really tracked in the way you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response - this is great input. I think I'm asking the wrong question here and need to dig further